# Django unicode of object id raise TypeError: coercing to Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have a django model named UserProfile.

Here is my code:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(id = 1).first()
if user_profile:
     user_profile_id = user_profile.id
     user_details = 'user id: ' + unicode(user_profile_id)
```

The code runs normally fine, but today I got an exception in line 4 (the last line):

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

I have no clue what possibly could have gone wrong here.

Comment: i think so your unicode getting None in the id due to which it's giving error because user_profile_id "id" doesn't exist and change django query to .get instead of filter, and do in try except

Comment: @jahmed31 this should not happen because she is passing the id to the Django filter .

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes if you are using filter and giving even None to the id it will give you empty query set so in that case it would be giving her error that this object doesn't have id

Comment: I don't see the point of this code: you query explicitly for id 1, then get the id from the resulting object - but naturally it will always be 1.

Comment: @jahmed31 if queryset is None then the if condition will fail . Id is a mandatory Field in Django models which cannot be set to None

Comment: @jahmed31 an empty queryset will fail the if condition

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I put their 1, just for the sake of presenting how I'm using the filter and first methods of Django orm.

Comment: The user profile object or it's id must not be None, otherwise I would've gotten error earlier, while accessing the object and it's id.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `unicode` getting `None` arguments, So change code like this,

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(id = 1).first()
if user_profile:
     user_profile_id = user_profile.id
     if user_profile_id:
         user_details = 'user id: ' + unicode(user_profile_id)
```

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of "Sometimes unicode getting None arguments", I can add the guard condition anyhow, but I need exact root cause of this error.